# Is there any way to get story mode only vehicles into online?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

I've seen videos of people getting tow trucks and stuff in online, however these videos are old (probably patched) or for consoles. Is there a way to do this on PC?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for exploits and questions about exploits (considered cheating by Rockstar Games) are off-topic [per this meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/489/how-do-we-stand-on-cheats-in-particularly-for-multiplayer-games).

Answer (score -1):

As time goes on yes glitches for bringing cars into online will arise. you might be able to find some glitches now if you look for it on youtube and other sites.

Comment: I know, I've seen these, but they all seem to be old and for console.

Comment: @Crubleigh I kn0w i own it on the console but the diffrence with PC is that Rockstar patched out all the bugs that allowed players to do it in the console so your best bet would be to wait for either 1. moddders/hackers to make/find a way or 2. Wait for a update to create possible glitches